# Left navigation menu needs to have slideout function

Tags: html

I am trying to get the left menu to slide the right submenu out when clicking on the relevant button. I was looking at plain javascrip but it seems that jquery might be a better / simpler option
Also, how would you go about hiding the submenu if you click outside of the navbar without having to add the X or 'close' clickable link to close the slideout submenu?

```
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
html, body {height: 100%;}
body {background: #fff; padding: 0; margin: 0; font-family: Myriad-Pro, Arial, 'Varela Round', sans-serif; font-size: 16px;}

.quotation-window {display: flex; height: 100%}
.window-container {display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; width: 100%;}
.header-one {display: flex; width: 100%; background-color: #dbdbdb; padding: 20px 10px;}
.header-two {display: flex; width: 100%; background-color: #afafaf; padding: 20px 10px;}
.content-container {display: flex; width: 100%; height: 100%}
.content-left {
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    width: fit-content;
}
.content-right {display: flex; background-color: #6d6d6d; padding: 20px 10px; width: 95%;}
.left-navbar {display: flex; width: 15vw; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; align-content: flex-start; padding: 20px;}
.left-navbar span {width: 100%; margin: 10px 0;}
.left-navbar a {color: #fff;}

.menu-links {display: flex; flex-direction: row; flex-wrap: wrap; align-content: flex-start; padding: 20px; background-color: #3f51b5; max-width: 200px; min-width: 200px;}
.menu-links span {width: 100%; height: fit-content; margin: 10px 0;}
.new-submenu {display: none; width: 100%; padding: 15px 20px; background-color: #5e69a8;}
.new-submenu ul {list-style-type: none;}
.new-submenu ul li {padding: 10px 20px;}
.new-submenu ul a {color: #fff;}
.hidden {display: none;}
.visible {display: block;}
.content-left span ul {list-style-type: none;}
span {
    display: none;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}
.content-container span ul {list-style-type: none;}


@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 340px) {
    .quotation-window {display: flex; height: 100%}
    .content-container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .content-left {
        height: fit-content;
        padding: 0;
        width: 30%;
    }
    .content-right {
        padding: 20px 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    ul {display: inline-flex;}
    .dropdown {display: inline-flex;}
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
</style>

<section class="quotation-window">

    <div class="window-container">
        <div class="header-one">header 1</div>
        <div class="header-two">header 2</div>
        <div class="content-container">
            <div class="content-left">
                <div class="menu-links">
                    <input type="button" value="div1" style="padding: 10px 20px; width: 100%;" />
                    <input type="button" value="div2" style="padding: 10px 20px; width: 100%;" />
                    <input type="button" value="div3" style="padding: 10px 20px; width: 100%;" />
                </div>

                <!--div class="menu-links">
                    <span id="new_Btn">New</span>
                    <span id="existing_Btn">Existing</span>
                    <span id="inventory_Btn">Inventory</span>
                </div -->
            </div>            

            <span id="div1">
                <ul >
                  <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
            <span id="div2">
                <ul >
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 7</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 8</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
            <span id="div3">
                <ul >
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 9</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 10</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 11</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu 12</a></li>
                </ul>
            </span>
            <div class="content-right">right column content</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
<script>
$('input').on('click', function () {
    var submenu = "#" + $(this).val();
    $('span').hide()
    $(submenu).show()
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check the snippet
it's quite easy in javascript but you have to structure your html a bit differently
here each sub is within the same div as the button which make it appear
sub has your class hidden

a generic function close all submenu putting hidden class

the click is checked at body level with a call to the function to close all submenu
if it contains the menu-links, the hidden class of the ul just after is removed.

you can fine tune sub apparition with css transition or animation as you wish.

```js
const clickBody = () => {
  document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', evt => {
    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
    closeAllSubMenu();
    if (evt.target.classList.contains('menu-links')) {
      let el_ul = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
      el_ul.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  });
};
window.addEventListener('load', clickBody);

function closeAllSubMenu() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.content-left ul').forEach(el => {
    el.className = 'hidden';
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Myriad-Pro, Arial, 'Varela Round', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.quotation-window {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%
}

.window-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-one {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.header-two {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.content-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.content-left {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content-left>div {
  padding: 1em 0;
}

.content-left>div button {
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.content-right {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  width: 95%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: block;
}

.content-container span ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="quotation-window">
  <div class="window-container">
    <div class="header-one">header 1</div>
    <div class="header-two">header 2</div>
    <div class="content-container">
      <div class="content-left">
        <div>
          <button class="menu-links">div1</button>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="menu-links">div2</button>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 8</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button class="menu-links">div2</button>
          <ul class="hidden">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 9</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 10</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 12</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content-right">right column content</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```